# iPhone mail using 700Mb with no accounts

Tags: iphone, email, mobile-mail

While trying to clear up space on my iPhone, I deleted all email accounts, as Mail was using well over 700Mb. I was expecting this to also clean up the excessive space being used by Mail, but it hasn't touched it - Mail is still using over 700Mb. I've powered off and back on again several times, and tried re-adding and removing the account multiple times, but Mail still uses loads of space.

Anyone have any ideas how to clean this up?

Comment: Very weird. Even with my email account linked, Mail and its data only takes up a meager 3.3 MB.

Comment: Is it IMAP or POP? Did you empty the Trash?

Comment: It was a google account. I can't get into the trash because I've deleted the account. Adding the account back shows an empty list until it can download the emails from the server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I have answered a number of questions with this particular solution, but let's go for it again.

Often times a *backup, wipe, restore* process will clear out the cruft still sitting around in the rather opaque IOS filesystem. I don't know why but it works:

1. *Backup:* Connect the iPhone to your computer and do a manual backup to that computer. Password protect the backup so you don't have to re-enter passwords.
2. *Wipe:* Once you have a good backup go into the iPhone > Settings > General > reset > Erase all content and settings. And let it do its thing.
3. *Restore:* Once the phone reboots and is waiting on it's welcome screen plug it back into your computer and restore it from the backup you just made.

9 times out of 10 all the inexplicable space usage on the phone goes away and you have got your space back.

Comment: Password-protecting the backup will also allow you to back up your Health data: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205220