# Why the system takes up almost all the storage of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, beta-seed-program, system-information

I barely installed apps on my iPhone, but it is obviously the system takes up almost all my storage?

iPhone 6: 15.9GB of 16GB used.

I do not know why. How to find the lost space on my phone?

I think it's fine before I started to try the iOS 12 Beta. How can I do it now?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What iPhone model do you have?

Comment: Iphone 6, 16GB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 12 beta. You should be submitting a bug report to Apple to check this, no? It might be leftover system files from iOS 11 or a way for you to go back and restore iOS. Point is. It is beta. So this question does not belong here.

Comment: It is likely a glitch in iOS beta. But the system does not completely fill the available storage of a 16GB iPhone. Try this trick it often fixes issues like this. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207965/33273

Comment: Fortunately, everything goes back to normal after I upgraded it to the official ios 12.