# System takes up 27gb of my iPhone's storage!

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I have an 64gb version of iPhone 6s iOS 11.4 installed. System keeps growing as I continue to use my phone (installing other apps, creating new files, ...). After it hit 35gb I tried deactivating and re-activating iCloud; it saved 8gb, system is now reduced to 27gb. Do you have any ideas, how can I fix this?

Comment: Go into settings -> general -> iphone-storage. It shoudl list the used space in categories like apps, photo's, media, etc. Check which category take sup the most space and see if you can remove some of that type of files.

Comment: iOS does not always use available storage efficiently. I have run across a solution that often fixes this kind of issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207965/33273

Comment: Is your phone jailbroken?